# How do you do a compare of more than or less than with string

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare, string-comparison

Hey guys I want to do some comparison with string by string but I don't know-how.

Like if the string of the user input is the same as the array then it will do something or not it will say not an array.

Does anybody have any suggestions to compare string? but is it possible to compare string? like the code below

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String Array[] = {"Henry", "Alex"};

System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
String ans = input.nextLine();
 
if (ans > array){
  System.out.println("Name is available");
} else {
  System.out.println("Name is not available"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see if a String is in an Array try

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Henry", "Alex");

    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    String ans = input.nextLine();
     
    if (list.contains(ans)){
      System.out.println("Name is in list");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Name is not in list");
    }
```

Comment: this one `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Henry", "Alex");` is actually Array List right?

Comment: yes, it is a shorter way of writing `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String []{"Henry", "Alex"});`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array and compare the string with each element. Once a match is found, you should print the `Found` message and break the loop. If a match is not found throughout the loop, print the `Not found` message after the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String array[] = { "Henry", "Alex" };

        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        String ans = input.nextLine();

        boolean found = false;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.equals(ans)) {
                System.out.println("Name is available");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("The name does not exist in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a name: Alex
Name is available
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a name: Nisha
The name does not exist in the array
```

Note that I have used a `boolean` variable, `found` to track if `ans` exists in the array. There is a way to do it even without using such an additional variable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String array[] = { "Henry", "Alex" };

        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        String ans = input.nextLine();
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(ans)) {
                System.out.println("Name is available");
                break;
            }
        }

        // If the loop has been completed without `break`, it means `name` does not
        // exist
        if (i == array.length) {
            System.out.println("The name does not exist in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a name: Alex
Name is available
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a name: Nisha
The name does not exist in the array
```

Comment: by the way, what does iterate means actually I don't quite understand that word. I see a lot of people saying that iterate the array but does it mean?

Comment: @NISHANAJIHAH - In programming, iterate means navigating an array, list, set etc. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 1):

There is not one way how to detect is value in the list. First you have to convert your array into list. And there is a methods:

### 1. Use 'contains' method

List have method called `contains()` which returns boolean value. True - if value/object is in the list, false - if value is not in the list.
**Example:**

```java
String[] array = {"apple", "orange"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
String value = "apple";

if (list.contains(value)) {
    System.out.println("Value is in the list");
} else {
    System.out.println("Value is not in the list");
}
```

This is the easiest way how to detect is array contains value/object. Also instead of using `.contains()` you can use `.indexOf()` method which returns -1 if value doesn't exist in array. It's the oldest way used in other programming languages as well: `if (list.indexOf(value) != -1)`.
The problem with these methods could be when entered value and values in array have a different char cases (upper/lower). To solve that you should iterate array and use same char case.

---

### 2. Iterating array

Iterating array values can solve problem when string value cases doesn't match.

**Example:**

```java
String[] array = {"Apple", "Orange"};
String value = "apple";

boolean isInArray = false;
for (String item : array) {
    isInArray = item.toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase());
    if (isInArray) {
        System.out.println("Value is in the list");
        break; // exiting array iteration when value was found
    }
}
if (!isInArray) { // if all array was iterated and no matching value was found
    System.out.println("Value is not in the list");
}
```

---

### 3. Use collection streams

This method works only with Java 8 and later versions. Then you can use lambda expressions for streams. But using streams could be redundant sometimes.

**Example:**

```java
String[] array = {"apple", "orange"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
String value = "apple";

boolean isInArray = list.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase()));
if (isInArray) {
    System.out.println("Value is in the list");
} else {
    System.out.println("Value is not in the list");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A bit of info from w3schools :

The equals() method compares two strings, and returns true if the strings are equal, and false if not.

Tip: Use the compareTo() method to compare two strings lexicographically.

A sample snippet of code :

```
String myStr1 = "Hello";
String myStr2 = "Hello";
System.out.println(myStr1.compareTo(myStr2));
```

This returns 0 if they are equal. If not it returns some value
you can run a if else by passing the returned value to a variable
if it equals 0 print equal
else print not equal

Hope i have answered

If you want to search and find if a string is in an array, please check this link for better info https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-in-java/

Comment: but wouldn't compareTo() only should true/false it as the result?

Comment: it returns 0 if equal and some value if unequal

Comment: The question seems to be checking if a String is in a String Array

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-in-java/